# DataTables - disable all features by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I attached DataTable to one of my tables in application:

```
var productList = $("#productList").DataTable({});
```

Unfortunately it completely reorganized my table. It changed the way it looked and added some more unnecessary (for now) buttons.

I need only one particular feature of DataTables for now - KeyTable. Is it possible to disable by default all features that comes with DataTables? Then, I would enable only those that I need right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 't',
    ordering: false,
    paging: false,

    keys: true, //enable KeyTable extension
});
```

The [`dom` option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) is an easy way to enable/disable certain functionality. I've disabled `ordering` and `paging`, you may want to look at the available ["feature" options](https://datatables.net/reference/option/) and see if anything else needs to be disabled.

Also, you probably don't want to load the default CSS (`jquery.dataTables.css`), since I assume you have already styled your table.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default properties like this. You can remove the unnecessary properties by setting false.

```
$.extend( true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
  "searching": false,
   "ordering": false
} ); 

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

Comment: yeah, I know, but I'm looking for easy way to disable all at once. Or at least I need a way to check which of them are enabled right now to know which have to be disabled.